# Magento payment method - can capture thru payment gateway, but refund and cancel dosent work

Tags: php, magento, payment

Hope someone here can give me a idear of whats going wrong in the payment method i am working on for Magento.

As the title says, the problem is cancel and refund from the admin.
The orders i place with this module can be captured from the gateway, when an invoice is made.

This is done in the model namespace/modulename/model/standard.php thats extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
The function name: capture

In this class i also have the functions void, cancel and refund. but they newer gets called.
I have tried to insert some Mage::Log() in these methods but nothing happens when the order is cancelled or a creditmemo is made (from the sales - invoice view).

So can anyone give me some hints on what i have missed - clearly i must have forgot something somewhere, but i really cant see where.

standard.php class:

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Standard extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{

const PAYMENT_TYPE_AUTH = 'AUTHORIZATION';
const PAYMENT_TYPE_SALE = 'SALE';

protected $_code = 'module';
protected $_isGateway               = true;
protected $_canAuthorize            = false;    
protected $_canCapture              = true;
protected $_canCapturePartial       = true;
protected $_canRefund               = true;
protected $_canRefundInvoicePartial = true;
protected $_canVoid                 = true;
protected $_canUseInternal          = true; 
protected $_canUseCheckout          = true;
protected $_canUseForMultishipping  = true;
protected $_canSaveCc               = false;

//this function is not called when order is cancelled
public function cancel(Varien_Object $payment)
{
    Mage::Log('order canceled');

    return $this;
}
//same with this function - not called when creditmemo is made
public function refund(Varien_Object $payment, $amount)
{

    Mage::Log('refund');
    return $this;
}
//but this is called, when invoice is being made
public function capture(Varien_Object $payment, $amount)
{

    return $this;
}
}
```

Comment: are there any errors in your exception.log or system.log? Have you turned on `MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1)`? Do you have the right method signature accepting a `Varien_Object $payment`.  Please post some code samples so we can see what you've done so far.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for your comment. MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE was not turned on, thanks for that hint. But anyway, nothing shows up in exception or system log.

Comment: @jonathan the class in question, or at least a small bit of it: class Namespace_Module_Model_Standard extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{public function cancel(Varien_Object $payment)
    {
     Mage::Log('order canceled');
     
     return $this;
    } so far i just want to see a entry in my system.log, so i know the function has been called, but nothing happens..

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, please edit the question and paste the code using the formatting tools so we can actually read it :)  I assume you've checked that Logging is enabled in System>Config>Developer?

Comment: @Jonathan Yes Logging is enabled in admin :)

Comment: do you have a solution? same problem for me...

Answer (score -1):

I hope this help someone!

For Credit Memo: 
You should create credit memo from the invoice, given that the invoice is generated from the payment and not created by admin user.
In "Order View (page)" > "Invoices (tab)" > "Select the invoice from the list" > "Credit Memo (button)" > "New Credit Memo for Invoice (page)" 
you should see two buttons "Refund Offline" and "Refund". "Refund" button will trigger your payment method model class methods processBeforeRefund(), refund(), processCreditmemo().